# php Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or `T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in codeigniter?

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

I am having troubles reading XML, I followed [this tutorial](http://blog.insicdesigns.com/2009/03/parsing-xml-file-using-codeigniters-simplexml-library/), and generated the code below.

When I open my controller I get

**Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_STRING' or`T_VARIABLE' or `T_NUM_STRING' in C:\wamp\www\ci_doctrine\system\application\controllers\welcome.php on line 49**

**line 49 is                 foreach($xmlData['item'] as $row)** I dont know what to do any idea, suggestions? help really appreciated

This is my code:

```
<?php

class Welcome extends Controller {

/*function Welcome()
{
    parent::Controller();   
}

*/

function index()
{


    //$this->load->view('welcome_message');


    //load the parser library
    $this->load->library('parser');

           $data['title'] = 'Parsing XML using Simplexml class of CodeIgniter';

           $data['products'] = $this->_getXML('myxml');

       $this->parser->parse('table_view', $data);

    //$this->load->library('parser');
        //$data['title'] = 'Parsing XML using SimpleXML class of CodeIgniter';

}

function _getXML($fname)
{

            $filename = $fname.'.xml';
            $xmlfile="“C:\wamp\www\" . $filename;
            $xmlRaw = file_get_contents($xmlfile);

            $this->load->library('simplexml');
            $xmlData = $this->simplexml->xml_parse($xmlRaw);

            foreach($xmlData['item'] as $row)
            {

        $result .= '<tr>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['id'].'</td>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['category'].'</td>';
        $result .= '<td>$ '.$row['price'].'</td>';
        $result .= '</tr>';

            }
             return $result;
    }

} 
//End of file welcome.php 
// Location: ./system/application/controllers/welcome.php 

?>
```

```
<item>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>iPhone</name>
    <category>Mobile</category>
    <price>300</price>
</item>

<item>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>iMac</name>
    <category>Desktop Computers</category>
    <price>2500</price>
</item>

<item>
    <id>3</id>
    <name>MacBook Pro</name>
    <category>Mobile PC</category>
    <price>2000</price>
</item>

<item>
    <id>4</id>
    <name>iTouch</name>
    <category>Gadgets</category>
    <price>150</price>
</item>

<item>
    <id>5</id>
    <name>Wii</name>
    <category>Gaming</category>
    <price>1250</price>
</item>

<item>
    <id>6</id>
    <name>Time Capsule</name>
    <category>Acessories</category>
    <price>1000</price>
</item>

<item>
    <id>7</id>
    <name>Apple TV</name>
    <category>Gadgets</category>
    <price>800</price>
</item>
```

Comment: What does your XML look like? Also, XSLT.

Comment: @Ignacio. I dont think the XML or XSLT would cause a PHP syntax error

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams I dont have a XSLT

Comment: I'm saying that you should use it, instead of processing the XML manually.

Comment: $xmlfile="“C:\wamp\www\" . $filename;  can you try to take double quote out should be $xmlfile="C:\wamp\www\"

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams what are the benefits of using xslt and can you post a link for processing a xml with xslt?

Comment: @Shakti Singh I already changed but now the error is in the line function index()

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function log_mesage() in C:\wamp\www\ci_doctrine\system\application\libraries\Simplexml.php on line 12 in function index()

Comment: The benefits are that it's drop dead easy to apply, and changes are made independent of the PHP code. The basic code goes something like this: `$xml = parseXml($xmlfile); $xslt = parseXml($xsltfile); $xmlresult = processXslt($xslt, $xml);`  See the XSLT section of the PHP docs for more info. Of course, there's also the stylesheet to create, but that's left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a double quote on `$xmlfile="“C:\wamp\www\"`

Comment: I already changed but the message doesnt dissapear

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
$xmlfile="“C:\wamp\www\" . $filename;
```

you are using back-slashes, which must be escaped. Change it to

```
$xmlfile="C:\\wamp\\www\\" . $filename;
```

Comment: thanks for answering, now the error is in the line  function index(), I will review the code any idea?

Comment: What's the error you are getting now? I don't see anything wrong there.